# Each substring of a certian length of a binary substring should have at least one '1' character

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm

You have been given a binary string containing only the characters '1' and '0'.

Calculate how many characters of the string need to be changed in order to make the binary string such that each of its substrings of at least a certain length contains at least one "1" character.

I came to think of the following idea but it fails for many testcases:

```java
public static int minimumMoves(String s, int d) {
        int n = s.length();
        
        int i=0, answer = 0;
        while(i<n)
        {
            boolean hasOne = false;
            int j=i;
            while(j<n && j<i+d)
            {
                if(s.charAt(j) == '1') 
                {
                    hasOne = true;
                    break;
                }
                j++;
            }
            if(!hasOne) {
                answer++;
                i += d;
            }
            else i++;
        }
        return answer;
}
```

Also my algorithm runs on O(|s|<sup>2</sup>) time. Can anyone suggest ideas on O(|s|) time?

Comment: Does the sliding window technique work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to break ensure there is no run of `d` zeros.

```
public static int minimumMoves(String s, int d) {
    int result = 0;
    int runLength = 0;
    for(char c: s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '0') {
            runLength += 1;
            if (runLength == d) { // we need to break this run
                result += 1;
                runLength = 0;
            }
        } else {
            runLength = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is elegant.

Comment: Assuming a String of `100010` needs broken up into `100` and `010` respectively, this code would have the wrong output for `minimumMoves("100010", 3);`

Comment: @TimHunter It gives `minimumMoves("100010", 3) == 1` https://repl.it/repls/PortlyDiligentNasm do you expect something else? I need to add 1 one in to obtain e.g. "100110", then each substring of length 3 contains a '1'.

Comment: I suppose that depends on details @KarthickShiva never gave us. Does the String have to be broken up into clear substring units of `100` and `010` which each contain at least one "1" character (and thus wouldn't need adjusted)? Or can the substring break down be applied to any continuous sequence of characters in the String?

Comment: @TimHunter It's stated "each of its substrings of at least a certain length", which seems clear enough to me. You can take any 3 or more consecutive characters.

Comment: Those words do not convey to me whether that applies to continuous substring units or block substring units. Can the same characters apply to multiple substrings in the break down or are they claimed and cannot be reused during the breakdown into substrings? That line does not state one way or another in that regard.

Comment: @TimHunter it seems clear to me that it means any continuous block of size `d` can be considered. So yes, the same character is part of many of them. But no need to argue more, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing off an idea:

```
return s.split("(?<=\\G.{" + String.valueof(d) + "})").stream().filter(str -> str.contains("1")).count()
```

Comment: You could even use parallelStream over stream.

Comment: You would have to make it `!str.contains("1")` since you're counting how many times it would need to be inserted, but otherwise this is identical to what I was thinking of.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct even after the @TimHunter 's suggestion. If s="000000000" and d=4, your code produces output as 3. But the correct answer is 2, I guess.

Comment: Is the `String.split()` method with the given regex really O(|s|)? Besides the unclear Big-O characteristics, Java regex is notoriously slow, especially when the regex still has to be compiled.

Comment: @KarthickShiva That's odd. Sounds like the answer check just discards the extra substring at the tail end of the String.

Answer (score 0):

I used the sliding window technique and Deque to solve this. This is my accepted solution:

```java
public static int minimumMoves(String s, int d) {
    int n = s.length();
    Deque<Character> dq = new LinkedList<>();
    int count = 0, answer = 0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<d; i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i) == '1') count++;
        dq.addLast(s.charAt(i));
    }
    
    if(count == 0) {
        answer++;
        count++;
        dq.removeLast();
        dq.addLast('1');
    }
    
    int i=d;
    
    while(i<n)
    {
        if(dq.getFirst() == '1') count--;
        dq.removeFirst();
        
        if(s.charAt(i) == '1') count++;
        dq.addLast(s.charAt(i));
        
        if(count == 0)
        {
            answer++;
            dq.removeLast();
            dq.addLast('1');
            count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    return answer;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a sliding window and a count of 1s so far at each index. Use a sliding window of `d` and if you don't see any ones so far, update the last index of that window with `1` and increment the result.

Code below:

```
public static int minimumMoves(String s, int d) {
    int n = s.length();
    int[] count = new int[n+1];
    int res = 0;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= d; i++ ) {
      if ( s.charAt(i-1) == '1') count[i] = count[i-1]+1;
      else count[i] = count[i-1];
    }
       
    
    if ( count[d] == 0 ) {
      res++;
      count[d] = 1;
    }

    for ( int i = d+1; i <= n; i++ ) {
      if ( s.charAt(i-1) == '0' ) {
        count[i] = count[i-1];
        int ones = count[i] - count[i-d];
        if ( ones == 0 ) {
          count[i] = count[i-1] + 1;
          res++;
        }
        
      } else {
        count[i] = count[i-1] + 1;
      }
      
    }

    return res;
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought of another implementation you can do for this by working from the maximum possible changes (assumes at start that all values are '0' in String), reduce it when it finds a '1' value, and then jump to the next substring start. This allows it to run in `O(n)` and `Ω(n/m)` (n = String length, m = Substring length).

```
  public static int minimumMoves(String s, int d)
  {
    char[] a = s.toCharArray();
    
    //Total possible changes (not counting tail)
    if(a.length < d)
      return 0;
    int t = (int) a.length / d;

    //Total possible changes (counting tail)
    //int t = (int) Math.ceil((double) a.length / (double) d);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
      if(a[i] == '1')
      {
        t--;
        //Calculate index for start of next substring
        i = (i / d + 1) * d - 1;
      }
    }
    
    return t;
  }
```

Comment: This is wrong, I guess. If s="00100" and d=2, your code's output is 1. But the correct output is 2.

Comment: @KarthickShiva You've been sending mixed comments about whether to count the tail end of the string, ie. the extra "0" at the end that doesn't fit in a whole substring length. That's why I put in the code for both accounting for it and not accounting for it. Comment out the not counting tail code, and remove the comments for the counting tail then.